# iPhone video thumbnail upside down

Tags: ffmpeg

Quicktime can play it right. But ffmpeg will produce an upside-down thumbnail sometimes.

```
ffmpeg -i input.MOV -ss 00:00:00.002 -vframes 1 -y output.png
```

I like to generate thumbnails of correct positions. What are some good remedies?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Videos recorded on mobile devices will have a rotation attribute in their metadata. Quicktime uses this to know if it need to rotate the video. Use "MediaInfo" to see your media's metadata, you can download it from here; https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download

If the video is rotated 90' use -vf 'transpose=1', for 180' use -vf 'hflip,vflip'

Comment: `ffprobe -i input.MOV 2>&1 | sed -n 's/rotate.*: \(.*\)/\1/p'` outputs the rotation too

Comment: `ffprobe -i input.MOV 2>&1 | sed -n 's/rotate.*: //p'` outputs the same thing